# npm rebuild node-sass still yields "Node Sass does not yet support your current environment: OS X 64-bit with Unsupported runtime (59)"

Tags: node.js, npm, frontend, gradlew, node-sass

I am getting the error:

```
Module build failed: Error: Node Sass does not yet support your current 
environment: OS X 64-bit with Unsupported runtime (59)
```

which, usually, can be mitigated by

1. Delete package-lock.json and node_modules
2. Run `npm install`
3. Run `npm rebuild node-sass`

However, I'm still getting the same error when trying to run my app locally with `./gradlew bootun` after these steps.

I am running with versions:

- Node: v8.11.3
- NPM: 6.2.0
- node-sass: 4.5.3

Are there any other tricks or things that I could be missing from my environment that anyone knows of?

Comment: I have had more success doing the same process but with `npm update` instead of `npm install`

Comment: I'll give it a shot and update

Comment: Still got the same error @SamWillis

Comment: Did you delete the "vendor" folder?

Comment: I went to the ./npm directoy through ll -thr    // to see the list of folders and there permissions. And gave permission - sudo chown -R $USER:$USER ABC_UI/